# Let $E$ be a vector space and $V$ its subspace. Is there a linear functional $f$ such that $\ker f = V$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I'm interested in below question.

> Let $E$ be a vector space and $V$ its subspace. Is there a linear functional $f$ such that $V = \ker f$?

A proof is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1840415/every-subspace-is-the-kernel-of-a-linear-map/1840429). However, the result seems to be not true in below simple example. Could you have a check on my counter-example?

> Now consider $E := \mathbb R^n$ with $\{e_1, \ldots, e_n\}$ being its basis. Let  $\{e_d, \ldots, e_n\}$ with $2<d<n$ be a basis of $V$. Clearly, the required $f$ has to sastify $f(e_i) = 0$ for all $i \ge d$ and  $f(e_i) \neq 0$ for all $i < d$. Let $\lambda_i := f(e_i)$ for all $i < d$. Let $a  := -\lambda_1 / \lambda_2 \neq 0$. Then $f(x) = 0$ with $x := e_1 + a e_2$. Clearly, $x \in \ker f$ and $x \notin V$. It follows that such $f$ does not exist.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. If you generalise your proof a little, you can show that kernels of linear functionals must have codimension $1$, meaning that summing a $1$-dimensional space directly to $\ker f$ recovers all of $V$ (or in the case of finite-dimensional vector spaces, $\dim \ker f + 1 = \dim V$).

Comment: @TheoBendit Just a remark: this is true only when $f \ne 0$

Comment: @TheoBendit It's strange that I come up with these answers https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1840415/every-subspace-is-the-kernel-of-a-linear-map/1840429.

Comment: @Analyst These are linear maps, not linear functionals. The specification that they map into $\Bbb{R}$ is very restrictive.

Comment: To be very clear, the difference is that they construct linear maps $E\to F$ for any vector space $F$, and you only want linear maps $E\to \mathbb{R}$ (so-called linear *forms*, or functionals as you call them, although that term is more common with infinite-dimensional spaces). This changes a lot what the kernel is allowed to look like.

Comment: For a linear mapping $f:V_1\rightarrow V_2$, dim$V_1$=dim$kerf$+dim$Imf$, so the dimension of $V_2$ has to be no less than the dimension of the space you choose minuses the dimension of the subspace you choose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have done is correct. More simply the kernel of $f$ has co-dimension $1$ unless $f \equiv 0$. So any $V$ whose co-dimension is more than $1$ would give a counter-example.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use the dimension formula for the linear mapping $f:E\rightarrow F$ where $\dim E = \dim ker(f) + \dim im(f)$.